# Occurance of NoSuchFieldError in my release app

Tags: android

This error is constantly occuring in one of the mobile brands such as Micromax. While in other phones with same Android version it is working fine. Below is the Screenshot of the Crash Report.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/SVpsS.jpg

Comment: NoSuchScreenshotError

Comment: Its edited check again

Comment: Are you using sqllite or interacting with json at any place in your code ?

Comment: No Iam not using any of these services in my code

Comment: aktools.phonesense, is that your package?

Comment: Yes that's my package name

Comment: Please provide full stackTrace.